# Modify colors of buttons connected to a IBoutletCollection not working

Tags: objective-c, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

I have this code should modify the colors of 24 buttons, connected to a IBoutletCollection :

In .h File:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

In .m File:

```
for (UIButton *label in buttons) {        
    label.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
    label.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor colorWithRed:87.0/255.0 green:49.0/255.0 blue:42.0/255.0 alpha:1]);
    label.layer.backgroundColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor colorWithRed:134.0/255.0 green:98.0/255.0 blue:98.0/255.0 alpha:1]);
    }
```

The IBOutletCollection's connected to the existing 24 buttons in my view, which is initially in gray color, when I run this function to modify the colors of the buttons they all go to the white color, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
 [[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
 [[myButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:87.0/255.0 green:49.0/255.0 blue:42.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor];
 [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0/256.0 green:150.0/256.0 blue:150.0/256.0 alpha:1.0]]
```

Comment: Ok For background color I do setBackgroundColor, now what I should use for borderWidth and border color?

Comment: first check if that takes color then use 

[[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[myButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];

Comment: if it works. 
kindly vote up my question and also tick my answer.thanks

Comment: yes, this method worked but the problem is that the color of the border I have to put a certain special color, and I believe could only get this kind of thing using the RGB or HEX, you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Hey man it works I try this: [[label layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:49.0/255.0 blue:42.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor];